# Crystal reports using wrong database at runtime with oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal report version 13.0.35, Oracle 11g (on another server) connected by oracle client (on my machine), Provider for oracle is OraOLEDB.ORacle in web.config and framework 4.00.

Report (using tables in datasource) shows data from wrong database though I am changing the connection at runtime.

Hint: reports that are using command or .xsd file are working correctly.
Hint: all crystal reports work fine with SQL Server.

```cs
public static void ConnectDocToDB (CrystalDecisions.Crystal Reports Engine.Report Document crReportDocument, bool? IsDataset = false)a
{
    string serverName =GetConnStrSection (connectionstring. ConnectionString ,"Data Source");
    string dataBase  = GetConnStrSection (connectionstring. ConnectionString, "Database");
    string userID= GetConnStrSection(connectionstring. ConnectionString, "User Id");
    string password =GetConnStrSection(connectionstring.ConnectionString, "Password");
    if (globals.DataBaseEngine == "Oracle")
        dataBase ="";
    //apply connection information to each sup report
    try
    {
        crReportDocument.SetDatabase Logon(user ID, password, serverName, dataBase);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    TableLogOnInfo tableLogin Info = new TableLogOnInfo();
    ConnectionInfo crConnInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    if (globals.DataBase Engine == "Oracle" && IsDataset == false)
    {
        CrystalDecisions.Shared.DbConnectionAttributes dbConnectionAttributes = new DbConnectionAttributes();
        dbConnectionAttributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("Server", dataBase));
        crConnInfo.Attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2(CrystalDecisions.Shared.DbConnectionAttributes.CONNINFO_DATABASE_DLL, "crdb_oracle/dll");
        crConnInfo.Attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_DatabaseType", "Oracle Server").
        crConnInfo.Attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_SQLDB", "1"));
        crConnInfo.Attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_ServerDescription", "dataBase"))
    }
    crConninto.ServerName = GetConnStrSection (connectionstring. ConnectionString ,"Data Source");
    crConninto.DatabaseName = GetConnStrSection (connectionstring. ConnectionString, "Database");
    crConninto.UserID= GetConnStrSection(connectionstring. ConnectionString, "User Id");
    crConninto.Password = GetConnStrSection(connectionstring.ConnectionString, "Password");
    if (globals.DataBaseEngine == "Oracle")
    {
        crConnInfo.DatabaseName="";
        crReportDocument.DataSourceConnections.Clear();
        crReportDocument.DataSourceConnections [0].Logon Properties.Clear();
        tableLoginInfo.ConnectionInfo = null;
    }
    tableLoginInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnInfo;

    //apply connection information to each table
    foreach (CrystalDecisions. Crystal Reports.Engine.Table table in crReportDocument.Database.Tables)
    {
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLoginInfo);
    }
    try
    {
        foreach (CrystalDecisions. CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument supReport in crReportDocument.Subreports)
        {
            try 
            {
                supReport.SetDatabaseLogon (userID, password, serverName, dataBase);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            foreach (Crystal Decisions. Crystal Reports. Engine. Table table in supReport.Database.Tables)
            {
                table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnInfo;
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo (tableLoginInfo);
            }
            supReport.DataSourceConnections[0].setConnection(serverName, dataBase, userId, Password);
        }
    catch
    {
        crReportDocument.DataSourceConnections[0].setConnection(serverName, dataBase, userId, Password);
    }
    crReportDocument.DataSourceConnections[0].setConnection(serverName, dataBase, userId, Password);
```

Comment: Hi just to confirm if your connection parameters are being picked from a different place, can you please try giving a wrong password and see if it works ?

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal it shows database logon failed